# How to arrange Windows in a specific order using Windows.Arrange?

Tags: excel, vba

I have opened more Excel Windows and I will arrange them with macros.
How could I decide the arrange of the windows?

At the moment the arrange of the windows is random.

If I make the arrange a second time, the windows will be arrange in an other order.

I used this script:

```
Windows.Arrange ArrangeStyle:=xlVertical
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub ArrangeWindows()

    'Windows are arranged. Left to Right in the reverse order of how they were last selected

    Windows("A.xlsm").Activate
    Windows("B.xlsx").Activate
    Windows("C.xlsx").Activate
    Windows.Arrange ArrangeStyle:=xlVertical
    
    'After the Arrange is executed, the last window selected remains the active window
    'Left to right position will be C, B, A

End Sub
```

If you then use the ribbon to arrange windows, the window that is used goes to the leftmost position and the others remain in their relative position.